# Holomorphic maps on 1-complex-dimensional tori with at least two holes

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

Is it possible to construct a non-bijective and non-constant holomorphic map from Riemann surface $S$ to itself where $S$ is homeomorphic to a compact surface of genus $g \geq 2$? What about the case when $S$ is homeomorphic to a compact surface of genus $g \geq 1$ with $p \geq 1$ points removed?

**Edit:** For the first case, one can prove that every non-constant holomorphic map on such a Riemann surface $S$ should be surjective and after it is possible to apply Riemann-Hurwitz formula to show that such a map can’t have critical points and has a degree one, so it should be a biholomorphism. This still works for the second case (with punctures) if we assume that our maps are surjective and have finite degrees, however I am not sure whether they are always surjective and how to prove non-existence of maps of infinite degree.

Comment: Do you know the Riemann-Hurwitz formula?

Comment: I guess it shows that there is no holomorphic non-bijective map of "finite degree" on these surfaces and probably it implies non-existence of any holomorphic non-bijective/non-constant map for the compact case. However, why can we prove non-existence of such maps of infinite degree (like $\exp$ or $\cos$ for $\mathbb{C}$) for the case with punctures?

Comment: There is a trick with passing to a covering space with  infinite cyclic fundamental group and using Riemann's removable singularities theorem to show that the singularities of the potential holomorphic map (at the punctures) are removable. If you edit your answer to indicate what you can prove yourself, I can add details on this.

Comment: I edited. Basically, it is clear for me how it works in compact case, but I am not sure about all the details in the non-compact ones.

Comment: Could you please, clarify what do you mean by a "hole"? There are three possible interpretations of this. For instance, some people say "torus with 2 holes" when they mean "a genus 2 surface."

Answer (score 3):

Here is an updated version of my original answer.

Let $f: X\to X$ be a nonconstant holomorphic map from a Riemann surface to itself. I will explain under which conditions you can conclude that $f$ is biholomorphic.

I will need some terminology.

**Definition.** A Riemann surface $X$ is said to have **finite type** if it is obtained from a compact Riemann surface $\hat{X}$ (the "completion" of $X$) by removing a finite subset (the "punctures" of $X$). A Riemann surface is said to have **finite topological type** if it is homeomorphic to a Riemann surface of finite type. A Riemann surface $X$ is said to have **hyperbolic type** if its universal covering space is biholomorphic to the unit disk. (By the Uniformization Theorem, every Riemann surface either has hyperbolic type or is $CP^1$ or its universal covering space is biholomorphic to the complex line.)

Note that if $\hat{X}$ has genus $\ge 2$ then $X$ has hyperbolic type; similarly, if $\hat{X}$ has genus 1 and $X$ has at least one puncture, then it has hyperbolic type; same when $\hat{X}$ has genus $0$ and $X$ has at least three punctures.

Riemann-Hurwitz formula implies that if $X$ has finite typerbolic type, then every nonconstant holomorphic self-map $f: X\to X$ is biholomorphic. (From the comments, you already know how to prove this, so I will not explain the argument.)

**Theorem 1.** Suppose that $X$ has finite hyperbolic type. Then every nonconstant holomorphic self-map $f: X\to X$ is biholomorphic.

In view of the remark above, the proof of Theorem 1 reduces to the following proposition on removable singularities:

**Proposition 1.** Suppose that $X, Y$ are a Riemann surfaces of finite and hyperbolic type. Then every holomorphic map $f: X\to Y$ extends to a holomorphic map $\hat{f}: \hat{X}\to \hat{Y}$.

Proof. The problem is "local": For every puncture $p\in \hat{X}-X$ and a small disk neighborhood $D$ of $p$ in $\hat{X}$, we have to show that the restriction of $f$ to the punctured disk $D^*=D-\{p\}$ extends to $p$, resulting in a holomorphic map $D\to \hat{Y}$. Since $\pi_1(D^*)$ is infinite cyclic, the image group
$$
H=f_*(\pi_1(D^*))< G=\pi_1(X)
$$
is also cyclic (infinite or trivial). Let $q:\tilde{X}\to X$ denote the covering space corresponding to the subgroup $H<G$; in particular, $\pi_1(\tilde{X})$ is cyclic and, hence, by the Uniformization Theorem, $\tilde{X}$ is biholomorphic either to the unit disk or to the annulus or to the punctured unit disk. In any case, by the covering theory, the map $f$ lifts to a holomorphic map
$$
\tilde{f}: D^*\to \tilde{X}, 
$$
i.e. $q\circ \tilde f=f$.

1. Consider first the easier case when $H$ is trivial, equivalently, $\tilde{X}$ is biholomorphic to the unit disk $\Delta$. Then $\tilde{f}$ has bounded image in the complex plane and, hence, $\tilde{f}$ extends to a holomorphic map $h: D\to \Delta$. Composing with $q$, we obtain the desired extension $\hat{f}: D\to Y\subset \hat{Y}$ of $f$.
2. There are no holomorphic maps from the punctured disk to the annulus inducing isomorphism of fundamental groups. (You can prove this also using Riemann's removable singularities theorem; I will leave it to you to work out the details.)
3. The most interesting case is when $\tilde{X}$ is (biholomorphic to) the punctured disk $\Delta^*=\Delta=\{z: |z|<1\} \setminus \{0\}$. One needs a bit of theory of Fucshian groups (Shimizu's lemma) to prove that there is a smaller disk $\Delta_r=\{z: |z|<r\}$, such that the image $q(\Delta_r)$ is a small disk neighborhood $D'$ of a puncture $p'\in \hat{Y}\setminus Y$ and, moreover, the (restricted) map $q: \Delta_r^*\to D'\setminus \{p'\}$ is a finite degree covering map.

Again, by Riemann's theorem, $\tilde{f}$ extends to a holomorphic map $h: D\to \Delta$, necessarily sending $p$ to $0$.  By shrinking the disk $D$, we get $h(D)\subset \Delta_r$. Hence, by composing $\tilde f$ with $q|\Delta^*_r$, we obtain the desired holomorphic extension of $f$ to the point $p$, namely, $\hat{f}(p)=p'$. qed

Suppose now that $X$ has finite topological type but not finite type. One can show (using the uniformization theorem) that there exists a compact Riemann surface with nonempty (real-analytic) boundary, $\hat{X}$, such that $X$ is biholomorphic to $\hat{X}\setminus (P \cup \partial \hat{X})$, where $P$ is a (possibly empty) finite subset of the interior of $\hat{X}$.

Ahlfors proved in

*Ahlfors, Lars V.*, [**Open Riemann surfaces and extremal problems on compact subregions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02567028), Comment. Math. Helv. 24, 100-134 (1950). [ZBL0041.41102](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0041.41102).

that there exists a nonconstant surjective holomorphic map $f$ from $\hat{X}$ to the closed unit disk (see the end of section 4.2 in the paper). I am sure there is a better reference, I just do not have one. Restricting $h$ to $X\subset \hat{X}$, we obtain a nonconstant holomorphic map $h: X\to D$, the open unit disk. Composing with a conformal embedding of $D$ to the surface  $X$, we obtain the desired holomorphic self-map $X\to X$. (It is clearly non-injective with one exception, namely, when $X$ is itself the unit disk. But then we can take $f(z)=z^2$.)

Lastly, consider the case when $X$ has finite non-hyperbolic type. Then $X$ always admits a nonconstant non-injective holomorphic self-map. The argument is a boring case-by-case analysis. For instance, if $X$ is ${\mathbb C}^*={\mathbb C} - \{0\}$, then you can use the exponential map. If $X$ is the quotient of the complex plane by a lattice $\Gamma$, then the map $z\mapsto 2z$ normalizes $\Gamma$ and, descends to a degree 2 holomorphic self-map of $X$.

Comment: Perhaps the OP edited, but it seems now that holes refer to genus, not punctures.

Comment: @TedShifrin: From the OP's comments, it appears that by "holes" they mean punctures. But let's wait to see what OP says.

Comment: Probably I shouldn't use the word "holes", because it led to misunderstanding. In fact, I meant genus by it. But it seems that provided argument perfectly works for the case when considered surface is obtained from a compact Riemann surface by making so many punctures, that Euler characteristic becomes negative.

Comment: However, I meant a bit more general situation. What I wanted to say is that if we take Riemann surface $X$ that up to homeomorphism is compact topological surface with finitely many puncture, then can we have any non-bijective/non-constant holomorphic map defined on $X$? This is more general, because, in particular, the annuli around punctures are not necessarily have modulus one (so they are not necessarily biholomorphic to punctured disk), but can have finite one. It seems that in this case, we can not always remove this "singularity".

Comment: @NP: Could you please revise the question making clear what you are asking. I will then revise my answer (a potential reader interested in this should not scroll through the comments to find out the exact meaning). And, also, do not  use the terminology "a hole" or "a torus" (except when your surface is  homeomorphic to $S^1\times S^1$). I very much doubt that the book from which you are learning the Riemann surface theory would contain such a terminology.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Done, I made the question more precise and  added proper terminology.

Comment: @NP: OK, I hope to update my answer in a few days, but, in short, unless all **ends** of the surface are punctures, there is always a nontrivial and non-injective holomorphic self-map.